# Starting my bot with npm start does not work! discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have been trying to do 'npm start' but everytime it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cedri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-29T21_11_03_910Z-debug.log
```

Yes! I did do a new package.json and yes I did do npm install! But it still does not work!

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "yuuto-giveaway",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Giveaway Bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "y!help"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Fun"
  ],
  "author": "BlueFire",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: It probably means you don't have a `start` script. Can you show your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a start script to your `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "y!help",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Comment: I get an error saying ```npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 299 while parsing '{```

Comment: You probably forgot to put a comma after `"test": "y!help"`